# Magento upgrade 1.4.x to 1.7 error

Tags: php, magento

I just updated a Magento shop from Magento 1.4.2 to 1.7.0

When I go to checkout, it gives following warning and doesn't show further page.

```
Warning: include(Mage\Eav\Model\Attribute\Data\Label.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in magento\lib\Varien\Autoload.php on line 93
```

Please tell me how can I fix this error.

Comment: FYI, Magento has its [own StackExchange site](http://magento.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Sounds like it's saying it can't find the file "Mage\Eav\Model\Attribute\Data\Label.php". Is it in fact there? That'd be a place to start looking.

Comment: yes there is not label.php but its not in default 1.7.0 neither its in 1.4.2. so why its looking for that file and how can I prevent it.

Comment: before upgrading check core files for any modification.I suggest you first upgrade to 1.5 then to 1.7.